# Is styptic powder OK to use after it gets damp?

Tags: dogs, safety, grooming

After trimming my dogs' nails, I accidentally left the jar of styptic powder open overnight. During that time, it absorbed some water from the atmosphere so that the top layer is slightly damp and clumps together. I'm concerned that having some water in the styptic would allow bacteria to grow.

Is this slightly damp layer still safe to use on my dogs? If not, what about the powder that was underneath the surface layer that is still dry? Can I do anything to dry it out, like heating it gently for a time?

Comment: I don't know about dogs, but I know with cats their claws can get very brittle as they get old. I've had a cat's claw split open exposing the quick when I trimmed nowhere near it - with properly sharp clippers, too. Also, it's very hard to tell how close you are with dark-nailed dogs (or dogs or cats with fur tufts between their pads)

Answer (score 4):

No!

Moisture breeds bacteria, styptic powder is a [antihemorrhagic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihemorrhagic).  It is used for medicinal properties on open bleeding wounds.

Best practice is to treat your pet's medicine and treatment with the same care and concern you would for yourself or your family.