# How can I more easily clip my ferrets' nails?

Tags: grooming, ferrets

I've been having some trouble clipping my ferrets nails. I try to scruff them and hold them still, but they just weasel out of the hold and run away. It's very frustrating to have go chasing after them, especially when I have to do the job myself. Is there an easier way to clip my ferrets' nails?

Comment: Properly holding them is the key. With older ferrets (7 years and more) I recommend a second person to help you holding them because otherwise the hold can hurt them.

Comment: @Sulthan - My ferrets are all about two years old so I haven't had to worry about that yet. Can you elaborate on a proper hold for older ferrets? Using the method in my answer, you don't actually have to hold them. They just lie on your lap and ignore you while you clip their nails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method has been working for me since I discovered it.

Get yourself a bottle of [Ferretone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002DHM4C). Lay your ferret on his/her back and put a few tiny drops on your ferret's belly. They will spend about 3 or so minutes licking up all of the Ferretone and ignore you completely while you clip their nails.

Just remember to use a small pair of accurate, sharp scissors and do not cut too close to the quick. You can injure your ferret and make the nail-cutting process more difficult in the future. If you're unsure of yourself with the scissors, keep some [styptic powder on hand in case you do cut the quick](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-can-i-prevent-cutting-my-dog-when-clipping-his-nails).

You can also check out [this guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Easy-Way-to-Cut-Your-Ferrets-Toenails/?ALLSTEPS) for pictures and video.

If you don't want to buy the Ferretone, extra virgin olive oil should also work as it is mostly the same thing as the Ferretone. This has been working on all four of my ferrets since I've had them.

Comment: I can confirm this has worked for every single one of my ferrets (there have been many). Only one didn't dig it at first, but I gave her a few chances and she came around.

Comment: I used ferretvite, but it was equally successful.